# program to display data sizes of all fundamental types in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, types, compiler-errors

When I work with a specific data type, I usually need to know the size it occupies in the program. Recently I thought of generic solution that would handle this problem for all data types in C++ language including type aliases and user-defined data types.

As I began implementing, I've realized it is not really easy to write a portable program for all platforms since data types in C++ are really compiler, architecture and operating specific entities.

It is mostly working but there are some edge-cases I can't handle and couple points which I am not sure about.

Brief Description of The Program:

The program uses Template Specialization to distinguish between
fundamental data types. Operations are compile-time and decision mechanism 
work via Template Specialization. Problem with that is if two types are deduced to the same type including type aliases, there happens to be compiler error(s).

A short example is:

"short" or "short int" or "signed short" may be all equivalent to "short int" as perceived by the compiler(of course this can be really compiler-specific trait). If "short" and "short int" are both provided to the program, template specialization mechanism complains that one is already defined.

So the question is:

How can I make sure, for example, whether types "short", "short int" or "signed short" will be deduced to the same type or not? Is there a way to check that at compile-time?

The situation is same for type aliases as well since template specialization occurs via their original type. Again, if both "short int" and "std::size_t" is provided, and if "std::size_t" happens to be defined "short int" by the system, the program doesn't compile because compiler complains that there is a specialized template for one already.

I've used following [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) to make sure what types are equivalent to each other but I suspect implementation the rules may not be followed by all compilers.

The output I am getting.

```
bool                    : 1 bytes | 8 bits
char                    : 1 bytes | 8 bits
signed char             : 1 bytes | 8 bits
unsigned char           : 1 bytes | 8 bits
wchar_t                 : 4 bytes | 32 bits
char16_t                : 2 bytes | 16 bits
char32_t                : 4 bytes | 32 bits
short int               : 2 bytes | 16 bits
unsigned short int      : 2 bytes | 16 bits
int                     : 4 bytes | 32 bits
unsigned int            : 4 bytes | 32 bits
long int                : 8 bytes | 64 bits
unsigned long int       : 8 bytes | 64 bits
long long int           : 8 bytes | 64 bits
unsigned long long int  : 8 bytes | 64 bits
float                   : 4 bytes | 32 bits
double                  : 8 bytes | 64 bits
long double             : 16 bytes | 128 bits
nullptr_t               : 8 bytes | 64 bits
Example                 : 168 bytes | 1344 bits
NULL macro is of integral type.
```

This is conceptually what I need:

```
bool                    : 1 bytes | 8 bits
char                    : 1 bytes | 8 bits
signed char             : 1 bytes | 8 bits
unsigned char           : 1 bytes | 8 bits
wchar_t                 : 4 bytes | 32 bits
char16_t                : 2 bytes | 16 bits
char32_t                : 4 bytes | 32 bits
short int               : 2 bytes | 16 bits
// -----------WHAT I NEED CONCEPTUALLY----------------
short                   : short is same as short int             //This would be a compile-time error normally.
signed short int        : signed short int is same as short int  //This would also be a compiler time error.
std::size_t             : std::size_t is of short int type.      //Since "short int" is already defined, this is compile-time error as well.
//-----------------------------------------------------
unsigned short int      : 2 bytes | 16 bits
int                     : 4 bytes | 32 bits
unsigned int            : 4 bytes | 32 bits
long int                : 8 bytes | 64 bits
unsigned long int       : 8 bytes | 64 bits
long long int           : 8 bytes | 64 bits
unsigned long long int  : 8 bytes | 64 bits
float                   : 4 bytes | 32 bits
double                  : 8 bytes | 64 bits
long double             : 16 bytes | 128 bits
nullptr_t               : 8 bytes | 64 bits
Example                 : 168 bytes | 1344 bits
NULL macro is of integral type.
```

Here is the code.

```
#ifndef TYPE_INFO_CPP
#define TYPE_INFO_CPP

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>

/*
    Just call:
        SYS_CHECK();
    In your main function
*/


//Types given into the template function as template parameters via macro
#define TYPES   bool,                       \
                char,                       \
                signed char,                \
                unsigned char,              \
                wchar_t,                    \
                char16_t,                   \
                char32_t,                   \
                short int,                  \
                unsigned short int,         \
                int,                        \
                unsigned int,               \
                long int,                   \
                unsigned long int,          \
                long long int,              \
                unsigned long long int,     \
                float,                      \
                double,                     \
                long double,                \
                std::nullptr_t,             \
                Example
//              std::size_t,                \
//              std::string::size_type

//Dummy Struct Declaration to enable Template Specialization
template <typename T>
struct TypeTraits;

//Template Specialization via macro
//Template Specialization is used to distinguish different types
#define REGISTER_TYPE(X)                                \
    template <>                                         \
    struct TypeTraits <X> {                             \
        static const char * name;                       \
    };                                                  \
    const char * TypeTraits<X>::name = #X;

//To get rid of std:: prefix during console output
#define INTRODUCE_NULLPTR_T()   \
    using std::nullptr_t;

//Example User-Defined Type Body
struct Example {
    char arr1[100];
    int a;
    double b;
    char arr2[50];
};

//These macros are short-hand for declaring specialized templates of the dummy template declared above
REGISTER_TYPE(bool)
REGISTER_TYPE(char)
REGISTER_TYPE(signed char)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned char)
REGISTER_TYPE(wchar_t)
REGISTER_TYPE(char16_t)
REGISTER_TYPE(char32_t)
REGISTER_TYPE(short int)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned short int)
REGISTER_TYPE(int)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned int)
REGISTER_TYPE(long int)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned long int)
REGISTER_TYPE(long long int)
REGISTER_TYPE(unsigned long long int)
REGISTER_TYPE(float)
REGISTER_TYPE(double)
REGISTER_TYPE(long double)

//Example User-Defined Type
REGISTER_TYPE(Example)

INTRODUCE_NULLPTR_T()
REGISTER_TYPE(nullptr_t)

template <bool T = std::is_integral<decltype(NULL)>::value, 
          bool U = std::is_pointer<decltype(NULL)>::value,
          bool Y = std::is_scalar<decltype(NULL)>::value>
void is_NULL_integral() {
    std::cout << "NULL macro is of ";
    if (T) {
        std::cout << "integral";
    }
    else if (U) {
        std::cout << "pointer";
    }
    else if(Y) {
        std::cout << "nulltpr_t";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "neither pointer nor integral or scalar";
    }
    std::cout << " type." << std::endl;
}

template <typename T, short int byte = 8>
void convert_byte_to_bit() {
    std::cout << " | ";
    std::cout << byte * sizeof(T) << " bits" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void _display_helper() {
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(23) << TypeTraits<T>::name << " : " 
        << sizeof(T) << " bytes" << std::left;
    convert_byte_to_bit<T>();
}

template <typename T>
void display_default_size() {
    _display_helper<T>();
}

template <typename T, typename U, typename ... Args>
void display_default_size() {
    _display_helper<T>();
    display_default_size<U, Args...>();
}

void SYS_CHECK() {
    display_default_size<TYPES>();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    is_NULL_integral();
}
#endif
```

Comment: Have you tried consulting `limits` header file?

Comment: What information am I supposed to find there?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure, for example, whether types "short", "short int" or "signed short" will be deduced to the same type or not? Is there a way to check that at compile-time?

You have tagged your question C++11 so... it's a work for type traits; `std::is_same`.

It works compile time.

By example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
 {
   constexpr bool b1 { std::is_same<short, short int>::value };
   constexpr bool b2 { std::is_same<short, signed short int>::value };
   constexpr bool b3 { std::is_same<short, unsigned short int>::value };

   std::cout << b1 << std::endl;  // print 1
   std::cout << b2 << std::endl;  // print 1
   std::cout << b3 << std::endl;  // print 0
 }
```

En passant: `short` and `short int` are alias for `signed short int`

**--- EDIT ---**

The OP ask

> Is there any mention in C++11 standard which states "short" and "short int" are indeed are alias for "signed short int"? Is there any resource I can use for looking up other fundamentals types as well?

I don't know where the standard mention it but is a fundamental aspect starting from the old C; you have linked a wonderful (IMHO) resource; in the page you link ([this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)) you can read

- that "The keyword int may be omitted if any of the modifiers listed below are used",
- that `signed` "is the default if omitted"
- and that "with all type specifiers, any order is permitted".

So (by example) `signed short int`, `short signed int`, `short int signed`, `signed int short`, `int signed short`, `int short signed`, `signed short`, `short signed` and `short` are alias for the same type.

Comment: Is there any mention in C++11 standard which states "short" and "short int" are indeed are alias for "signed short int"? Is there any resource I can use for looking up other fundamentals types as well?

Comment: @ugarbd - answer improved; hope this helps.